# BIDS 2008: How to write to a text file destination in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, bids

I am used to DTS Pkgs where i can just write to a text file using a data transform task.

How can i do the equivalent of this in SSIS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Data Flow task in SSIS.  Create the Data Flow task.  Add an appropriate source component to get the data.  Then add a Flat File Destination.  The destination can be configured to your file requirements.  Connect the two objects and map the columns.